# placeholder in input feild in wordpress is not working in mobile device

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website in wordpress using Jupiter theme but placeholder in contact form is not displaying in mobile phone and working properly in desktop.
for example your placeholder in YOUR PHONE NUMBER than in mobile it displays only YOUR and PHONE NUMBER does not seen.

```
     .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .mk-textarea::-        
     webkit-input-placeholder,
      .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-input::- webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)
      }
      .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .mk-textarea:-     
      ms-input-placeholder,
     .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-  input:-   ms-input-placeholder {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)
      }
     .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .mk-textarea:-   moz-placeholder,
    .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-  input:-    moz-placeholder {
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)
      }
     .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light   .mk-textarea:focus,
     .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-  input:focus {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
      color: #fff
       }
      .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light    .mk-textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
      .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-          input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)
     }
    .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light          .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-input:focus:-    ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)
    }
   .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light       .mk-textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder,
   .mk-contact-form-wrapper.outline-style.contact-light .text-  input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)
  }
```

And php code is here

```
    if($style == 'outline') {
    $output .= $fancy_title;
    $output .= '<div class="mk-contact-form-wrapper mk-shortcode contact- '.$skin.' outline-style '.$el_class.'">';
   $output .= '<form class="mk-contact-form" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate">';
   $output .= '<div class="mk-form-row">';
   $output .= '<input placeholder="'.__( 'Your Name', 'mk_framework'  ).'" type="text" required="required" name="contact_name" class="text-input  '.(($phone == 'true')? 'two-third' : 'half').'" value=""   tabindex="'.$tabindex_1.'" />';
   if($phone == 'true') {
    $output .= '<input placeholder="'.__( 'Your Phone Number',   'mk_framework' ).'" type="text"  name="contact_phone" class="text-input  two-third" value="" tabindex="'.$tabindex_2.'" />';
    }
    $output .= '<input placeholder="'.__( 'Your Email', 'mk_framework'   ).'" type="email" required="required" name="contact_email" class="text-input    '.(($phone == 'true')? 'two-third' : 'half').'"  value="" tabindex="'.$tabindex_3.'" />';
  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= '<div class="mk-form-row"><textarea required="required"  placeholder="'.__( 'Your message', 'mk_framework' ).'"  name="contact_content" class="mk-textarea" tabindex="'.$tabindex_4.'"> </textarea></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="mk-form-row"><textarea  placeholder="'.__(  'Insert area of your interest', 'mk_framework' ).'" name="contact_content1"   class="mk-textarea custom" tabindex="'.$tabindex_6.'"></textarea></div>';
```

Comment: Based on your code, and the screenshot provided, I can't help.

Comment: We have no clue where to start as we do not have enough information. Please add URL or more details like plugin used for contact form etc..

Answer (score -2):

placeholder attribute support only PC based browser not for mobile try to use another techniques for placeholder.